# Does `block_given?` render `&block` parameter optional?

Tags: ruby, yield, ruby-block

I am comfortable with the following:

```
def some_def(foo, &block)
    puts "block utilized below"
    block.call(foo)
end

def some_other_def(bar)
    puts "using yield below"
    yield bar
    puts "and back into the method"
end
```

So I have learned to keep blocks (and procs) separate from the `yield` keyword.

However, I ran into the following code:

```
# ./open_file.rb

class File
    def self.open(name, mode, &block)
        file = new(name, mode)
        return file unless block_given?
        yield(file)
    ensure
        file.close
    end
end
```

It seems the parameter `&block` does not matter when I implement execute this code in irb:

```
irb -r ./file.open.rb
```

and do something like:

```
File.open('foo.txt','r') {|f| puts f}
```

Is `&block` rendered optional by `block_given?` in:

```
return file unless block_given?
```

Comment: You can use either form, interchangeably.

Comment: `&block` parameter is _always_ an optional parameter, with or without `block_given?`. However, running `block.call` (or `yield`, for that matter) when `block` is `nil` (which is the default value when it is not provided) will break things; so when `&block` is used, usually you'll _want_ to check `block_given?`. Thus, you have a case of _reverse causality_: It's not that `block_given?` causes `&block` to be optional; it's that `&block` being optional makes programmers use `block_given?`.

Comment: @Amadan you can simply check via `if block` in that case.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, AFAIK the two are synonymous if there is an explicit block parameter. Maybe I was misreading OP's question? If OP meant "Is `&block` rendered _unnecessary_ by `block_given?`", then here, in a way, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you only use the `&block` argument if you need to pass the block to another method such as in this made up example:

```
def m(&block)
  some_array.map(&block)
end
```

or this real version of [`Enumerable#sum` from Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L48):

```
def sum(identity = nil, &block)
  if block_given?
    map(&block).sum(identity)
  else
    sum = identity ? inject(identity, :+) : inject(:+)
    sum || identity || 0
  end
end
```

In either case, the block that the method is called with is used with another method call so you need a way to refer to the block (i.e. a name).

So `block_given?`/`yield` and `&block` serve different purposes. Being able to call `block_given?` doesn't make `&block` redundant and, as in the `#sum` implementation above, they can even be used together.

Comment: Wonder why they didn't use `inject(identity) { |sum, e| sum + yield(e) }` instead and a default `identity` value of `0` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The `&block` in the method signature accepts a block, converts it into a proc, and assigns it to a variable named `block`. In case a block is not provided, `block` is assigned `nil`.

Whether to use the argument `block` within the method definition does not matter just like it does not matter whether an ordinary method argument `bar` is used or not in the following definition:

```
def foo(bar); end
```

However, accepting a block as a parameter and not using it is redundant and waste of resource. It may perhaps still make sense to explicitly indicate to a fellow programmer that the method accepts a block.

Using `block_given?` is independent of all this. It is independent of whether a block has been accepted as an argument via `&`. It refers to the block directly, irrespective of `block`.